# upload xml to mysql php - Insert No value in table

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Here is .xml format :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><!--File Created By Call Logs Backup & Restore v3.21 on 29/08/2013 19:53:23--><?xml-stylesheet type="xsl" href="calls.xsl"?>
<calls count="500">
<call number="+919257035805" duration="0" date="1377691732581" type="3" readable_date="28/08/2013 17:38:52" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
<call number="+919257035805" duration="38" date="1377691747866" type="2" readable_date="28/08/2013 17:39:07" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
</calls>
```

Here is .php script

```
if ($_FILES[xml][size] > 0) { 
$file = $_FILES[xml][tmp_name]; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $count = 0;
foreach ($xml->call as $call) {
$number = mysql_real_escape_string($call->number);
$duration = mysql_real_escape_string($call->duration);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($call->type);
$readable_date = mysql_real_escape_string($call->readable_date);
$contact_name = mysql_real_escape_string($call->contact_name);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO call_log (number, duration, type, readable_date, contact_name ) VALUES ('$number', '$duration', '$type', '$readable_date', '$contact_name')") or die ("Error in query: $insert. ".mysql_error());

    }

//redirect 
    header('Location: upload_sql.php?success=1?inserts=' . $count . ''); die; 

}
```

But this script dose not add any value to Table......completely blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read attribute values the wrong way. You need to use array call:

```
$number = mysql_real_escape_string($call['number']);
$duration = mysql_real_escape_string($call['duration']);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($call['type']);
$readable_date = mysql_real_escape_string($call['readable_date']);
$contact_name = mysql_real_escape_string($call['contact_name']);
```

When you use `$call->number` SimpleXMLElement object tries to get child node `<number>` which does not exist in `<call>`.

One other thing, what is field type of `readable_date` in DB?
If it is `VARCHAR` then no problem, but if `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` during insert mysql will convert to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` which is wrong so you should first convert it to proper DB datetime format:
It is easier to convert already present UNIX timestamp `$call['date']` using `date()` function than convert `$call['readable_date']`

```
$readable_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (int) $call['date']);
```

But since it seems to me your `date` and `readable_date` do not match same dates you may need to properly convert it:

```
$readable_date = convertDate($call['readable_date']);
```

Function for conversion:

```
function convertDate($in)
{
   preg_match('#^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$#', $in, $matches);
   return $matches[3] . '-' . $matches[2] . '-' . $matches[1] . ' ' . 
        $matches[4] . ':' . $matches[5] . ':' . $matches[6];
}
```